# Need help making a sum calculation faster in python

Tags: python, math, sum, integral, notation

Here is a piece of my code with the summation. It includes an integral. all the variables peppered in there have float or integer values.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import scipy.integrate
from mpmath import nsum, inf

sum1 = nsum(lambda m: (1/(math.factorial(m))*((ra/a1)**(2*m))*(1/(math.factorial((m+1)-1)))*(scipy.integrate.quad(lambda u:((u**((m+1)-1))*(math.exp(-u))) ,0,(d**2)/(4*(a1**2)),limit = 50))[0]),[0,100])
```

Is there any way I can make this faster? I need to be able to loop through this several hundred times. For the moment it's taking more than an hour. Here is the original complete equation. The part of my code that I pasted here is just the first sum (sigma) in the equation where m goes from 0 to infinity. I changed it to m from 0 to 100 in my code here temporarily.

[image: original equation]

Many thanks!

Update:

I've tried a different way. I think those who've commented were right and I was using scipy incorrectly before. I think I've fixed that. It is still slowish for my purposes, but now only takes 30min for several hundred repetitions. (I'm also guessing you can use either the "def" structure or "lambda" structure to pass through quad). I'd appreciate if you have any advice for making something like this faster, but I appreciate you guys helping lead to the answer.

```
for m in range(0,100):

    # def integrand(u,m):
    #     return (u**((m+1)-1))*(math.exp(-u)) 

    f = lambda u,m:(u**((m+1)-1))*(math.exp(-u)) 
    
    sumfunc =1/(math.factorial(m))*((ra/a1)**(2*m))*(1/(math.factorial((m+1)-1)))*scipy.integrate.quad(f,0,(d**2)/(4*(a1**2)),args=(m,))[0] 
    
    tosum.append(sumfunc)
    
sum1 = sum(tosum)
```

Comment: This isn't written properly and that's why it's taking over an hour. The quad function in scipy is actually pretty fast. As of now, I can't tell what you are trying to do so I can't help much but if you add the full equation that you are trying code out in written form - I might be able to correct your code.

Comment: Could you write the equation you're trying to solve out? The code is difficult to read and it's hard to understand what you're trying to do. In the future you may also want to use [Black](https://black.now.sh) to format code this lengthy before posting.

Comment: got it, thanks, I've included the original equation in the original post. sorry for not being clear in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `mpmath` knows [gammainc](http://mpmath.org/doc/current/functions/expintegrals.html?highlight=gammain#mpmath.gammainc), use it;
2. `npsum` is smart, don't try to be smarter, just sum to infinity. It'll do some fancy computations to stop just when it needs to;
3. if you care about precision, try to use `mpmath` types as much as possible

So here's the code:

```
from mpmath import *

a1 = mpf('0.62')
ra = mpf('0.99')

def the_sum(d, a, **kwargs): # added `a` for reuse in the complete formula
    r_ = (ra / a) ** 2
    d_ = d ** 2 / (4 * a ** 2)
    return nsum(
        lambda m: r_ ** m / factorial(m) * gammainc(m + 1, 0, d_, regularized=True),
        [0, inf],
        **kwargs
    )
```

and some benchmark

```
%time [sum_OP(d) for d in range(5)]                                                                                                                                                                
CPU times: user 684 ms, sys: 2.97 ms, total: 687 ms
Wall time: 685 ms
[mpf('0.0'),
 mpf('0.93752967676144794'),
 mpf('5.3589089548240878'),
 mpf('10.711751972234245'),
 mpf('12.600516476806067')]

%time [the_sum(d, a1) for d in range(5)]                                                                                                                                                               
CPU times: user 28.7 ms, sys: 1.3 ms, total: 30 ms
Wall time: 28.8 ms
[mpf('0.0'),
 mpf('0.93752967676144794'),
 mpf('5.3589089548240905'),
 mpf('10.711751972234246'),
 mpf('12.600516476806067')]
```

If you really want to makes things faster, want to be smarter than `nsum`, and are confident it will work in this case (I do), you can tell it to use the `direct` method:

```
 %time [the_sum(d, a1, method='d') for d in range(5)]                                                                                                                                               
CPU times: user 20.7 ms, sys: 613 µs, total: 21.3 ms
Wall time: 20.9 ms
[mpf('0.0'),
 mpf('0.93752967676144794'),
 mpf('5.3589089548240905'),
 mpf('10.711751972234246'),
 mpf('12.600516476806067')]
```

Finally, as it seems you don't need any multiprecision, no need to use mpmath, and stick to some low precision version:

```
a1 = 0.62
ra = 0.99
def sum_low_prec(d, a):
    return sum(
        (ra/a)**(2*m) / (math.factorial(m)) * scipy.special.gammainc(m + 1, (d**2)/(4*(a**2)))
         for m in range(30)
    )

%time [sum_low_prec(d, a1) for d in range(5)]                                                                                                                                                     
CPU times: user 871 µs, sys: 3 µs, total: 874 µs
Wall time: 877 µs
[0.0,
 0.9375296767614478,
 5.358908954824089,
 10.711751972234243,
 12.600516476806066]
```

Comment: thanks for the breakdown of each of these options. very informative